# R can not recognize date in format

Tags: r, date

folk!

R can not recognize the next type of date: "Jun 3, 1986"

I tried it several times converting that column to factor or character.

The next examples from stackoverflow do not work and return "NA":

1. sdate2 <- "jan151999"
   ndate2 <- as.Date(sdate2, "%B%d%Y"); ndate2
2. dates <- c("May 27 1984", "July 7 2005")
   betterDates <- as.Date(dates,
   format = "%B %d %Y")

I used small letter %b and it did not work also.

3. My version does not work as well
   as.Date("Jun 3, 1986", format = "%b %d, %Y")

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably because your locale language is different. Change it to English and it should work.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
as.Date("Jun 3, 1986", format = "%b %d, %Y")
#[1] "1986-06-03"
```

Comment: great! That was a reson! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

And also this way works well. SOme oone suggested it but deleted afterward.

lubridate::mdy("Jun 3, 1986")